# How do I use inheritance in Unity3d MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, swift, inheritance, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

So I began learning Swift, but I discovered that I wanted to use Unity3d because it looked interesting to learn, and for games it looked like the better option than Xcode. This meant that I had to learn a new language, however, so I started learning C#. In my project I have 2 classes.

My first Class is LivesDetract. This class is an edge collider. It catches the falling objects, and decreases the life amount:

```
public class LivesDetract : MonoBehavior {

     public int currentLives; //set to 3 in Unity
     private int livesDecrementAmnt = 1;

     void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
         currentLives = currentLives - livesDecrementAmnt;
    }
}
```

The second class is named GameController. GameController controls the flow of the game. I originally had LivesDetract as a part of GameController, but for organization purposes, I think it should be in its own class. The problem is that I get the following error when I try to inherit from the class LivesDetract:

Error:
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LivesDetract.currentLives'"

```
public class GameController : MonoBehavior {

    IEnumeratorSpawn () {
       while(LivesDetract.currentLives > 0) { // This line is where the error occurs
        //Game Actions Occur
       }
    }
}
```

I think I have provided enough information, but if more is needed let me know.
In Swift I was able to set the function as a variable:

```
var livesDetract = LivesDetract()
```

I could then use:

```
while livesDetract.currentLives > 0 {
}
```

That doesn't seem to work in C# though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access currentLives without instantiating the object. You need find the object in Unity before making use of it.

Comment: Isn't Instantiate used to create clones of an object? I don't want to clone the collider.

Comment: I don't mean that you need to use that method. If that's a game object you probably need to find it first. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html